# Match regex letters and number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex to match strings like:

```
63PDH
XX1PF  
HX11F
```

where there are numbers and digits. Can't match only numbers or letters and must be 5 like above.

I did the following expression with a little research, but i can't get the match with 5:

```
([A-Z]*([0-9]+[A-Z]+))
```

I need something like this:

Match any 5 characters sequence where there are are letters and numbers.

```
([A-Z]*([0-9]+[A-Z]+)){5}
```

Anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: Are you simply looking for `([0-9A-Z]{5})` maybe …?

Comment: I tryied, but this match only letters or only numbers sequences

Comment: No idea what you mean - https://regex101.com/r/Y0mgd6/1

Comment: I'm sorry, i edited the question. There was a mistake. I can Only match when there are letters and numbers in the sequence like 63PDH for example. HJDFS or 90876  can't match

Comment: You must define precisely what should match and what should not. Write down all the rules that apply.

Comment: the regex must match any group of 5 characters if this group contains letters and numbers: match example: 63PDH, KJ1JH. Not match: HJDFS, 90876. if the group is bigger than 5, can't match either, like: 63PDWEDN33 for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the rules are

- must contain both A-Z and 0-9
- length of 5

Then I would write three checks using three look-aheads:

```
^                   # start of string
(?=[0-9A-Z]{5}$)    # contains 5 characters in 0-9 and A-Z before the end of the string 
(?=.*?[0-9])        # contains at least one 0-9 anywhere
(?=.*?[A-Z])        # contains at least one A-Z anywhere
.*                  # actual match
```

The "actual match" can be `.*` since all the other rules are guaranteed to be met by the look-ahead conditions. The `.*` must be there however, because look-aheads themselves don't consume any characters.

On one line

```
^(?=[0-9A-Z]{5}$)(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*
```

To use the regex successfully on multi-line input, you need to enable the multi-line flag, so that `^` and `$` change their meaning to "line-start" and "line-end" instead of "string-start" and "string-end".

Answer (score 1):

I think that don't have good answer.

Because it check very very many case.

I think you should check it with 2 regex:

> First regex check 5 character (number or letter).
>
> Second regex check 5 numbers or 5 letters ( and ignore it).

Comment: Thanks. You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your example:

```
^(?=.*\d+)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+).{5}$
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/nqr06FBwsx

Answer (score 0):

Another idea to use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for checking the string does not consist of only [digits](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `(?!\d*$)` or only non-digits `(?!\D*$)` and define the allowed characters that are `[A-Z\d]{5}`.

```
^(?!\d*$|\D*$)[A-Z\d]{5}$
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UhzO93/2)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use conditionals

`^(?:(\d)|([A-Z])|[\dA-Z]){5}$(?(1)(?:(?(2)|(?!)))|(?!))`